# Rails and graphql casing convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

I am starting to dive into graphql, building my first API with Rails. I have tons of questions regarding standards and conventions.

For example, I noticed the gem `graphql` by default requires the fields to be passed in CammelCase, when actually when I used to build RESTful API in Rails I always received the arguments in snake_case.

So I was wondering, is CammelCase the convention for Graphql? Should I still use it in my API? All my tests would assert the responses are in snake case too, is that correct?

Comment: The Gem will juggle the casing for you in most cases. So when you build types, for example, you can define the fields as snake_case. The Gem will always assume that the client is using the GraphQl convention, which is camelCase. I would refer to the official GraphQL docs for that information: https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#type-system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly up to you and your application, and some libraries will automatically convert to and from camelCase, but given the choice, the [GraphQL Rules website](https://graphql-rules.com/) highly recommended that you just commit to using camelCase for all GraphQL fields and arguments, then convert those to camel_case fields in Ruby where necessary.

From the [GraphQL Rules website](https://graphql-rules.com/) website:

> Rules and recommendations mentioned here were the results of 3 years' experience of using GraphQL both on the frontend and backend sides. We also include the recommendations and experience of Caleb Meredith (PostGraphQL author, Facebook ex-employee) and Shopify engineers.
>
> 1. Naming rules
>
>    1.1. Use camelCase for GraphQL-fields and arguments.
>
>    1.2. Use UpperCamelCase for GraphQL-types.
>
>    1.3. Use CAPITALIZED_WITH_UNDERSCORES to name ENUM-types.

I wish a bit that I had followed these for some past projects, but hey, they are still running just fine though :), but there has been churn where occassonally we were faced with some inconsistencies and chose to convert some fields.

Comment: `then convert those to camel_case fields in Ruby where necessary.`

Just to clarify, did you mean convert those to snake_case? fields in Ruby where necessary?

Comment: @DavidLee Yes. The Graphql-Ruby gem will automatically convert Ruby's snake_case to GraphQL camelCase, for instance: `field :current_user, UserType, null: true` in Ruby, will generate as `currentUser` in your GraphQL schema.